# Is there a way to stop writing same subqueries again and again when joining subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I need to full outer join these subqueries

```
SET @n1 = 0; 
SET @n2 = 0; 

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT (@n1:=@n1 + 1) AS n, name FROM occupations WHERE occupation="Doctor") AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT (@n2:=@n2 + 1) AS n, name FROM occupations WHERE occupation="Professor") AS t2 
ON t1.n=t2.n
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT (@n1:=@n1 + 1) AS n, name FROM occupations WHERE occupation="Doctor") AS t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT (@n2:=@n2 + 1) AS n, name FROM occupations WHERE occupation="Professor") AS t2 
ON t1.n=t2.n
;
```

Here I had to write the same subqueries again and again.

If there is any method like below it will be very easy

```
SET @n1 = 0; 
SET @n2 = 0; 

t1 = (SELECT (@n1:=@n1 + 1) AS n, name FROM occupations WHERE occupation="Doctor");
t2 = (SELECT (@n2:=@n2 + 1) AS n, name FROM occupations WHERE occupation="Professor");

SELECT * FROM  t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.n=t2.n
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN AS t2 ON t1.n=t2.n;
```

But I don't know any method to do something like that. Also I don't want to create any views or temporary tables to do this. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: What is your purpose of using `SELECT (@n1:=@n1 + 1) AS n` ?

Comment: I am trying solve hackerrank.com problem. I can solve problem.But it takes too many codes.Here [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem) to the problem

Comment: Can you post the problem (or a similar one) here?

Comment: Reading & writing the same variable in a select statement is undefined in MySQL & as of 8 is deprecated. See the manual re variables & assignment.

Comment: Read about CTEs, which are available in MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot questions are usually tackled using conditional aggregation in mysql for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(name varchar(10), job varchar(10));

insert into t values
('aaa','dr'),
('bbb','plumber'),
('ccc','lab'),
('ddd','dr'),
('eee','plumber'),
('ggg','lab'),
('fff','plumber')
;


select max(case when job = 'dr' then name else null end) dr,
         max(case when job = 'plumber' then name else null end) plumber,
         max(case when job = 'lab' then name else null end) lab
from
(
select name,job,
        if(job <> @p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=job p
 from t 
 cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:='') r
 order by job, name
 ) s
 group by rn;

+------+---------+------+
| dr   | plumber | lab  |
+------+---------+------+
| aaa  | bbb     | ccc  |
| ddd  | eee     | ggg  |
| NULL | fff     | NULL |
+------+---------+------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Note the generation of a row number to enable the group (in version 8.0 you could use row_number function) and the ordering by name.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know about this case method. I could do what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I were able to do what i wanted to do. Here is my code. Thank you everyone.

```
SET @n1 = 0; 
SET @n2 = 0; 
SET @n3 = 0;
SET @n4 = 0;

select t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name from
(select 
    (@n1:=@n1 + 1) AS n,
    case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name else null end as name
from occupations
order by if(occupation = 'Doctor',0,1), name) as t1,
(select 
    (@n2:=@n2 + 1) AS n,
    case when occupation = 'Professor' then name else null end as name
from occupations
order by if(occupation = 'Professor',0,1), name) as t2,
(select 
    (@n3:=@n3 + 1) AS n,
    case when occupation = 'Singer' then name else null end as name
from occupations
order by if(occupation = 'Singer',0,1), name) as t3,
(select 
    (@n4:=@n4 + 1) AS n,
    case when occupation = 'Actor' then name else null end as name
from occupations
order by if(occupation = 'Actor',0,1), name) as t4
where t1.n=t2.n and t2.n=t3.n and t3.n=t4.n and not(t1.name is null and t2.name is null and t3.name is null and t4.name is null);
```